# remove the untagged

Tags: discussion, tags

Whilst exploring the site I came across this tag [untagged](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)

I have gone through and re-tagged the questions as appropriate(awaiting review)

and i think that this tag should be removed as there is no need for this tag all lit does is make types of questions hard to find.

The tag has no description and the questions that are in there clearly belong to existing tags. I believe that this tag should be removed

Answer (score 3):

[untagged](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is a pseudo-tag; it's what shows up if a question has no tags of its own.  It can't be removed.  When you come across a question with this tag, please try to apply other tags as you're doing.  (Thanks for the help!)

But wait, you might ask -- how can this ever happen in the first place, when you can't post a question without supplying at least one tag?  I know of two cases (migration and tag burnination), but it doesn't look like either applies here -- those questions weren't migrated, and I can't think what tag they might have once shared that would have been destroyed.

Comment: Haha thanks I did not realise this was the case but I did attempt to retag all of those question I found with that tag

Comment: I approved your edits, but we need one more approval for them to take effect.

Comment: Sweet hopefully more people review them soon